# Which message sends when I click on line separator in CSplitterWnd?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, csplitterwnd

I have pane with vertical divider line. When I move this line on top or bottom, I got size message to List, which exists inside pane. But I can't find handler which responsible for messaging when I just click in line without moving.

My problem is: I make one click on line, without dragging, and all my controls which places in bottom pane has disappears. SetFocus doesn't work:(

Thank you

Comment: Can you add some code related to your problem?

Comment: Which piece of code do you need?

Comment: Actually my code that I wrote works fine, I have trouble when I just click on separator line, I didn't write nothing to this line

Comment: Have you used Spy++ to check the messages?

Comment: yes I used. It still on place!

Comment: Update question, please. vertical divider or horizontal one? Post the code you have for creating/setting the spliter and code handling size change

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to find the handler. Use Visual Studio's Find In File to search for "CSplitterWnd::OnLButtonDown" in the MFC source folder. When it finds that line you can double click on the line in the Find Results window and the source code will open at that line.

Comment: And, Spy++ would show this easily without looking up the code.